# Service 'ifplugd' working erratically if ethernet cable unplugged at boot time

Tags: ubuntu, usb, ethernet, hot-plug, arm64

*[Ubuntu kernel 18.04.4 5.4 arm64]*

I use a USB network card (with `udev` renaming to `usb0`). There is no issue if the UTP cable was connected at boot. In that case, I can unplug the UTP and plug it again. It works smoothly.

If the cable is unplugged at boot then hot-plugin will not work. To solve this problem I installed `ifplugd`, but it works erratically.  When I checked the service status in each scenario I get:

**scenario 1- `ifplugd` service not working for `usb0`:**

```
# service ifplugd status
● ifplugd.service - LSB: Brings up/down network automatically
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ifplugd; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-09-21 16:43:02 UTC; 20s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 893 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ifplugd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 21 16:43:02 umbrela-bridge systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Brings up/down network automatically...
Sep 21 16:43:03 umbrela-bridge ifplugd[893]:  * Network Interface Plugging Daemon...
Sep 21 16:43:03 umbrela-bridge ifplugd[893]:  * skip usb0...
Sep 21 16:43:03 umbrela-bridge ifplugd[893]:    ...done.
Sep 21 16:43:02 umbrela-bridge systemd[1]: Started LSB: Brings up/down network automatically.
root@umbrela-bridge:/home/umbrela#
```

**scenario 2- `ifplugd` service working for `usb0`:**

```
# service ifplugd status
● ifplugd.service - LSB: Brings up/down network automatically
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ifplugd; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-09-21 16:46:26 UTC; 1min 55s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 884 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ifplugd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2291)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ifplugd.service
           └─912 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i usb0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I

Sep 21 16:46:25 umbrela-bridge systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Brings up/down network automatically...
Sep 21 16:46:26 umbrela-bridge ifplugd[884]:  * Network Interface Plugging Daemon...
Sep 21 16:46:26 umbrela-bridge ifplugd[884]:  * start usb0...
Sep 21 16:46:26 umbrela-bridge ifplugd(usb0)[912]: ifplugd 0.28 initializing.
Sep 21 16:46:26 umbrela-bridge ifplugd(usb0)[912]: Using interface usb0/00:0E:C6:00:01:01 with driver <ax
Sep 21 16:46:26 umbrela-bridge ifplugd(usb0)[912]: Using detection mode: SIOCETHTOOL
Sep 21 16:46:26 umbrela-bridge ifplugd(usb0)[912]: Initialization complete, link beat not detected.
Sep 21 16:46:26 umbrela-bridge ifplugd[884]:    ...done.
Sep 21 16:46:26 umbrela-bridge systemd[1]: Started LSB: Brings up/down network automatically.
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

Any help appreciated.